Trying to build OpenJDK on Windows 11 with Cygwin64 but get error: "Cannot locate a valid Visual Studio installation"
Trying to build OpenJDK on Windows 11 with Cygwin64 but get error: "Cannot locate a valid Visual Studio installation"
I installed Oracle JDK 22.
I ran the Visual Studio Setup exe and installed both Build Tools 2019, and also Visual Studio 2022.
I enabled the checkboxes in both for Desktop Development with C++.
I tried shortnames but failed. I opened Administrator window in both Powershell and CMD but both gave "Access is denied"
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> cd 'C:\Program Files'
PS C:\Program Files> fsutil file setshortname "Microsoft Visual Studio" MICROS~3
Error:  Access is denied.
PS C:\Program Files>
Someone else suggested
$ bash configure --enable-debug --with-toolchain-path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\bin\Hostx64\x64" --with-toolchain-version=2022
and also without the path
$ bash configure
and also with 2019
$ bash configure --enable-debug --with-toolchain-path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\bin\Hostx64\x64" --with-toolchain-version=2019
all give error:
configure: Using default toolchain microsoft (Microsoft Visual Studio)
configure: error: Cannot locate a valid Visual Studio installation
configure exiting with result code 1

Could you try with a unix/cygwin style path? e.g. --with-toolchain-path="/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools"

bash configure --enable-debug --with-toolchain-path="/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.40.33807/bin/Hostx64/x64" same error

You need to drop the trailing /MSVC/14.40.33807/bin/Hostx64/x64, Oh, and try --with-tools-dir. I don't think --with-toolchain-path is used on Windows

@JornVernee same error $ bash configure --with-toolchain-path="/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools"
I also added this to the Windows PATH environment.

Using: bash configure --with-boot-jdk=/cygdrive/c/zulu-21 --with-tools-dir=/cygdrive/c/VisualStudioCommunity/VC/Auxiliary/Build
